# Can't make update query

Tags: codeigniter, foreach

I have in my view 4 selects with the same name - wrappingType[]. They are for 4 different sizes. I tried but I couldn't make update cycle to update data in database.
I want when user selects from these 4 selects - these values to be updated in database in 4 different rows - for the 4 different sizes(XL,L,M,S). 
I don't know how to make it for these 4 sizes - they are input.
It is looking in this way:
http://prntscr.com/7g7o49

I want when user selects an option from each of the 4 dropdowns, their values to be updated where this eggsize is.(XL,L,M,S). How to do this cycle - foreach, for? And how to get value of egg size - I have made these input text boxes for this goal, but I coulnd'do it. :)
Here is my view:

```html
<?php 
foreach($items as $item){
   if($item['eggSize'] == 'XL'){
      $size_wrappingType = $item['wrappingType'];
      $size_quantity = $item['quantity'];
     
                        
 <?php
  }
}
 <select name = 'wrappingType[]' >
     <option value="<?= '0' ?>"
     <?php echo $size_wrappingType == '0' ? 'selected="selected"' : 
      '' ?>><?php echo '0'  ; ?></option>  
     <option value="<?= '4' ?>"
      <?php echo $size_wrappingType == '4' ? 'selected="selected"' : 
     '' ?>><?php echo '4'  ; ?></option>
<input type="text" name ="eggsize[]" value ="XL">
<?php
foreach($items as $item){
   if($item['eggSize'] == 'L'){
      $size_wrappingType = $item['wrappingType'];
      $size_quantity = $item['quantity'];
     
                        
 <?php
  }
}
 <select name = 'wrappingType[]' >
     <option value="<?= '0' ?>"
     <?php echo $size_wrappingType == '0' ? 'selected="selected"' : 
      '' ?>><?php echo '0'  ; ?></option>  
     <option value="<?= '4' ?>"
      <?php echo $size_wrappingType == '4' ? 'selected="selected"' : 
     '' ?>><?php echo '4'  ; ?></option>
</select>
<input type="text" name ="eggsize[]" value ="L">

//And these selects are 4 - for sizes - XL, L, M, S
```

My model is:

```html
<?php 
 public function update_document($document,$order_id){
     if($this->input->post('eggsize')) {
        foreach($this->input->post('eggsize') as $size) {
     if($this->input->post('wrappingType')) {
          foreach($this->input->post('wrappingType') as $wrappingType) {
     $data = array(
     'wrappingType' =>$wrappingType,
     );

                $this->db->where('idOrder', $order_id);
                $this->db->where('eggSize', $size);
                $this->db->update('orderitems', $data); 
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify how many select (drop downs), input text boxes you have in your form. It is not clear from the code and the question is ambiguous.

Comment: I have 4 dropdowns and 4 inputs. With these 4 inputs I have tried to get what is the size of the eggs - if they are XL, L,S or M. Because in my view first I show XL, next L, M, S. I have to show data for these 4 egg sizes and when user update WrappingType from select, it should be changed in database this wrappingType where this egg size is. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only need one for loop, to loop through every `wrappingType` input, and then get the corresponding `eggsize` input and use it in your update query.

```
public function update_document($document,$order_id) {
    $eggSizeInputs = array();
    if($this->input->post('eggsize')) {
        $eggSizeInputs = $this->input->post('eggsize');
    }

    $eggSizeIndex = 0;

    if($this->input->post('wrappingType')) {
        foreach($this->input->post('wrappingType') as $wrappingType) {
            $data = array(
                'wrappingType' =>$wrappingType
            );

            $eggSize = $eggSizeInputs[eggSizeIndex++];


            $this->db->where('idOrder', $order_id);
            $this->db->where('eggSize', $eggSize);
            $this->db->update('orderitems', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I have to clear my logic, not to have more than one row to be with the same orderId and eggsize :)

Comment: I have forgotten. I have one more input type box. It is for quantity of eggs - for each size of eggs, I have this input. it is: <?php // echo $size_quantity;  
             $data =array(
                'name' => 'size_quantity[]',
                'value' => $size_quantity
              );
            echo form_input($data); ?> How to insert it for each eggSize?

Comment: I tried now with this: It's giving me notice-Uninitialized string offset: 1: $size_quantity = array();
    if($this->input->post('size_quantity')) {
        $size_quantity = $this->input->post('size_quantity');
    }
    $size_quantityIndex = 0; if($this->input->post('wrappingType')) {
        foreach($this->input->post('wrappingType') as $wrappingType) {     $size_quantity = $size_quantity[$size_quantityIndex++];
            $eggSize = $eggSizeInputs[$eggSizeIndex++];
            $data = array('wrappingType' =>$wrappingType,            'quantity' => $size_quantity
            ); }